# Google spread sheets equivalent for SQL SUM (if (condition, val1, val2))

Tags: sql, google-sheets

What is the Google Spreadsheets equivalent for the following SQL query?

```
SELECT SUM (IF (a = 'P', 1, IF (a = 'H', 0.5, 0))) FROM sheet;
```

I want to find the sum of a derived column, where the value of the derived field is 1 (when `a = 'P'`) or 0.5 (when `a = 'H'`).

**Update** - Based on Kiel Labuca's comment, I have obtained a working solution. It is more of a work around. It works because the derived values are constants and are not based on the original value. Is there a real solution to this?

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B32, "=P") + COUNTIF(B2:B32, "=H") / 2
```

Comment: `sum(if (...))`is non-standard SQL. (There is no `IF` in SQL) to which dialect are you referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Spreadsheet SUM Function Overview

Adding up rows or columns of numbers is one of the most common operations carried out in all spreadsheet programs.

To make it easier to accomplish this task, Google Spreadsheets includes a built in formula called the SUM function.
The SUM Function's Syntax

A function's syntax refers to the layout of the function and includes the function's name, brackets, and arguments.

The syntax for the SUM function is:

```
=SUM(number_1,number_2,...number_30)
```

Up to 30 numbers can be summed by the function.
The SUM Function's Arguments

number_1, number_2,...number_30 - the data to be added up

The arguments can contain:

```
a list of numbers to be summed
a list of cell references indicating the location of the data in the worksheet
a range of cell references to the location of the data
```

Example: Add a Column of Numbers Using the SUM Function

```
Enter the following data into cells A1 to A6: 114, 165, 178, 143, 130, 165

Click on cell A7 - the location where the results of the function will be displayed

Click on Insert > Functions > SUM in the menus insert the SUM function into cell A7

Drag select cells A1 to A6 in the spreadsheet to enter this range as the function's argument

Press the ENTER key on the keyboard

The number " 895 " should appear in the cell A7, this is the sum of the numbers entered in cells A1 to A6

When you click on cell A7 the complete function =SUM ( A1:A6 ) appears in the formula bar above the worksheet
```

Source: [Google Spreadsheets SUM Function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/googlespreadsheets/ss/2011-07-20-google-docs-spreadsheet-tutorial-sum-function.htm)

Comment: My question was specifically on how to get the sum of a virtual column, derived from an existing column.

Comment: @JoyceBabu Sorry! you could try this one `=SUMIF(range1:range2,"=P", derivedField)` or `=SUMIF(range1:range2,"=H", derivedField)`

Comment: How do I define the `derivedField`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand why your COUNTIF solution is a workaround and "not a real solution", because mathematically it does exactly what you require. You could express it in a different way:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B2:B32,{"P";"H"})*{1;0.5}))`

or something like this is more explicitly similar to your SQL query example:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(B2:B32="P",1,IF(B2:B32="H",0.5.0))))`

but it is possible that your solution is more efficient than either of these.

Comment: My code works in this particular case, because 1 and 0.5 are constants. But if I wanted to get the sum of values from another column of the matching rows, it wouldn't work.

Comment: In that case, are you able to rephrase your question? Because that would be entirely possible, it's just that I don't know what you're asking. Eg "if B2:B32 is 'P', sum the value from D2:D32; but if B2:B32 is 'H', sum the value from F2:F32", or something.